# How to send a Serialized object from a server to an Android App

Tags: java, android, web-services, sockets, rmi

I need to send an object built in server to my Android app. I'm looking for the best way to do that. I dunno if the best choice is just JSP with binary output, or maybe RMI or just sockets. Google Cloud Messaging should be my choice, but It seems Im needing a supporting server for this technologie.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: I think we need more details.  What kind of object?

Comment: GCM is pretty easy to setup over HTTP. Depending on the size of what you're trying to send this can work. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I need to send (on demand) custom objects of variable size. From 1 - 5 Kb single objects with tiny attributes, until Arrays of 4 -5 objects including static images.

Can I use GCM on a Tomcat Server? Need I mantain a listening socket all the time?